# LTSpice RF transistor 2 emitter "the instance has fewer connection terminals than the definition"

Tags: rf, bjt, ltspice, npn

I am trying to use the Infineon spice model for [BFP640ESD](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/rf-wireless-control/rf-transistor/ultra-low-noise-sigec-transistors-for-use-up-to-12-ghz/bfp640esd/) ([link for library file](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/rf-wireless-control/rf-transistor/ultra-low-noise-sigec-transistors-for-use-up-to-12-ghz/bfp640esd/#!?fileId=5546d46256fb43b30157577dffb04549)), but it has two emitter terminals and I'm not sure how to use it since the BJT models have only 3 terminals and I need 4.

Spice code added below:

```
***************************************************************
*   Infineon    Technologies    AG
*   GUMMEL-POON MODEL   IN  SPICE   2G6 SYNTAX
*   VALID   UP  TO  10  GHZ
*   >>> BFP640ESD   <<<
*   (C) 2012    Infineon    Technologies    AG
*   Version 2.1 November    2012
***************************************************************
* - Please use the global SPICE GP parameter TEMP to specify the
*   junction temperature of the device in your application to get
*   correct simulation results. This procedure is necessary because
*   the GP model does not consider the self heating of the device.
* - TEMP is calculated by TEMP=TA+Pdc*(RthJS+RthSA). The junction
*   temperature TEMP is the sum of the ambient temperature TA and
*   the increment of temperature caused by the dissipated DC power Pdc.
* - RthJS is the thermal resistance between the junction and the
*   soldering point. RthJS for this device is 310 K/W. RthSA is the
*   thermal resistance of the PCB, from the soldering point to the
*   ambient. For determination of RthSA please refer to Infineon's
*   Application Note "Thermal Resistance Calculation" AN077.
* - The model has been verified in the junction temperature range
*   -25°C to +125°C.
* - TNOM=25 °C is the nominal ambient temperature during measurement
*   for the parameter extraction. Please do not change this value.
****************************************************************
*.OPTION TNOM=25, GMIN= 1.00e-12
*BFP640ESD C B E1 E2
.SUBCKT BFP640ESD 1 2 3 4
*
CBEPAR 22 33 2.29E-013
CBCPAR 22 11 7.095E-014
CCEPAR 11 33 2.024E-013
LB    22 20 6.623E-010
LE   33 30 1.519E-010
LC   11 10  6.522E-010
CBEPCK 20 30  4.4E-014
CBCPCK 20 10  1E-015
CCEPCK 10 30  4.4E-014
LBX    20 2 3.607E-010
LEX   30 35 5.524E-011
LCX   10 1  2.452E-010
*
RE1 35 3 1E-03
RE2 35 4 1E-03
*
D1 33 25 M_D1
D2 41 25  M_D2
*
RBLfdb 22 25 1.754
*
R_PW_fbd 41 33 7.5
R_PW_e11g 42 33 2.1
R_sub_fbd 41 5 477
R_sub_e11g 42 5 350
R_CS_npn 55 5 424.1
RSUB 30 5 0.001
*
D3 42 15 M_D3
D4 23 33 M_D4
D5 23 15 M_D5
*
RLDNBL 15 11 10.63
*
Q1 11 22 33 55 M_BFP640ESD
*
.MODEL M_D1 D(
+ IS=3.5E-015
+ N=1
+ RS=6.1
+ CJO=1E-014)
*
.MODEL M_D2 D(
+ IS=6E-015
+ N=1
+ RS=0.01
+ CJO=9E-015)
*
.MODEL M_D3 D(
+ IS=9E-015
+ N=0.9973
+ RS=160
+ CJO =2E-014)
*
.MODEL M_D4 D(
+ IS=3.5E-015
+ N=1
+ RS=0.2
+ CJO =2E-014)
*
.MODEL M_D5 D(
+ IS=3.5E-015
+ N=1.02
+ RS=4.7
+ CJO =3.003E-014)
*
*
.MODEL  M_BFP640ESD NPN(
+   TNOM = 25
+   IS  =   9.658E-016
+   BF  =   557.2
+   NF  =   1
+   VAF =   192.2
+   IKF =   0.09128
+   ISE =   3.626E-014
+   NE  =   2
+   BR  =   246.5
+   NR  =   0.9955
+   VAR =   1.577
+   IKR =   0.004397
+   ISC =   1.27E-014
+   NC  =   1.322
+   RB  =   4.406
+   IRB =   0.0006534
+   RBM =   0.8094
+   RE  =   0.2638
+   RC  =   4.042
+   XTB =   -2.576
+   EG  =   1.11
+   XTI =   0.15
+   CJE =   3.798E-013
+   VJE =   1
+   MJE =   0.1016
+   TF  =   2.172E-012
+   XTF =   1.084
+   VTF =   0.5626
+   ITF =   0.3839
+   PTF =   0.28
+   CJC =   5.346E-014
+   VJC =   0.7186
+   MJC =   0.8649
+   XCJC    =   1
+   TR  =   2E-009
+   CJS =   1.404E-013
+   MJS =   0.07264
+   VJS =   0.4
+   FC  =   0.3
+   KF  =   7.116E-011
+   AF  =   1.7)
***************************************************************
.ENDS BFP640ESD
```

Comment: That link requires a `myInfineon` account.

Comment: Hi Ste, I dont see an attach file option so I edited the post and just pasted the model code. Notice the pin configuration BFP640ESD C B E1 E2. That E2 is what I need to know how to connect

Comment: OK, I just made a symbol, but when I run it I get all this error "Error on line 4 : v1 n003 0 v Unknown parameter "v"" and a ton of warning about less than two connection and empty pin current

Comment: Thanks.  I understand how to solve this now.  Can you tell us what SPICE program you are using?

Comment: Im using LTSpice. Is there something better for this I should try?

Comment: ok that v known was jut a voltage source I didn't give a value. But now I'm running a common emitter test and sweeping base voltage and cant get the dang thing to conduct! Sorry I'm brand new to spice.

Comment: I tested the circuit with the generic transistor model and it worked :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subcircuit text shows that the two external emitter connections are simply shorted together internally via a 1mΩ resistor each.  Nodes 3 and 4 are E1 and E2 respectively, and the resultant node after connecting them together is node 35.

```
RE1 35 3 1E-03
RE2 35 4 1E-03
```

There are a few ways to handle this.  First, is to convert the subcircuit to 3 terminals so you can use a standard NPN symbol with it.  You can either ignore the 2nd emitter connection (since it's negligible) or if you want to be a stickler you can use the parallel equivalent of the two 1mΩ connections to form a single emitter that's 500µΩ.  I'll do the latter by changing the `.subckt` line to `.SUBCKT BFP640ESD 1 2 3`, change the `RE1` line to `RE1 35 3 500u` and delete the `RE2` line completely.  After those changes, the beginning of the file would look something like this:

```
.SUBCKT BFP640ESD 1 2 3
*
CBEPAR 22 33 2.29E-013
CBCPAR 22 11 7.095E-014
CCEPAR 11 33 2.024E-013
LB    22 20 6.623E-010
LE   33 30 1.519E-010
LC   11 10  6.522E-010
CBEPCK 20 30  4.4E-014
CBCPCK 20 10  1E-015
CCEPCK 10 30  4.4E-014
LBX    20 2 3.607E-010
LEX   30 35 5.524E-011
LCX   10 1  2.452E-010
*
RE1 35 3 500u
*
D1 33 25 M_D1
D2 41 25  M_D2
*
```

The final step to make this work is to `ctrl+rightclick` the NPN symbol in LTspice to change the "Prefix" field from `QN` to `X` which allows you to use it for subcircuits.

[image]

---

A more direct approach (which doesn't require experienced analysis of the `.subckt` in question) would be to use the `npn4` symbol which has a 4th terminal.  It's originally meant for the substrate connection, but since you are using a `.subckt` instead of a `.model` it doesn't matter and just provides you with an extra terminal.  I will use this extra terminal as the 2nd emitter and tie them together in the schematic.  We still have to change the "Prefix" field as was done above.

[image]

---

Last is the method you hinted at in your question's comments, which is the auto-generated symbol which can be used with any `.subckt`.  Instead of re-explaining this, I'm just going to link to the Analog Devices website [which already has a tutorial on it](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html).

[image]

---

Comment: Wow thank you for the detailed and speedy response! So I did the third method and built the circuit you show and the output is 0V for me and not 1.2V. Can you share your simulation file?

Comment: tried method one and I get "unknown subcircuit called in: xq1 n001 n002 n003 bfp640esd"

Comment: ok probably just was referencing and old library file. Pasted a spice directive with the code and it works now! :)

Comment: @JosiahCochran Yeah, you need to `.lib xxx.lib` for the first two examples. There's some kind of hierarchical order for how it attempts to find the file which I don't 100% remember but it's something like it first looks in the schematic directory and then looks in `Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sub` after that. I typically keep all my models in that `\sub` directory since that is my preference. The auto-generated symbol does an auto `.lib` command so that's why in my screenshot it's not there. Pasting the library text directly on the schematic has the benefit of making the schematic portable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the SPICE model already includes the very low inductance of the dual_emitters